# Obtaining averages based on two conditions

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have dataframe of average weekly temperature from 2010 to 2019 of cities around the world. So my dataframe looks like this:

```
date         city     avg_temp   week
2010-01-01   madrid   25         1
2010-01-08   madrid   26         2
2010-01-16   madrid   22         3
...
```

I want to create a new dataframe that averages all years into weeks by city. It could look like this:

```
week         city     avg_temp_2010to2019
1            madrid   25         
2            madrid   26         
3            madrid   22         
...
```

I have the average weekly temperature data for 2020 and the idea is to contrast/predict the 2010-2019-set against the 2020-validation-set. The final result could look like this

```
week         city     avg_temp_2010to2019 avg_temp_2020
1            madrid   25                  24
2            madrid   26                  26
3            madrid   22                  21
...
```

I know this can be done using .groupby(), but that creates another issue. If I do this:

```
data.groupby(['city', 'week']).avg_temp_2010to2019.mean()
```

...I get a pd.Series that looks like this:

```
city         week     avg_temp_2010to2019
madrid       1        25         
             2        26         
             3        22  
...
```

The problem with that pd.Series is that I cannot add another column - the 2020 data. In other words, this does not work:

```
df_with_groupby['2020'] = df_other['2020']
```

I have fried my head trying to figure a viable way but I cannot seem to find a solution. Any help would be much appreciated.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When i understand it right you don't need the exact date column. So maybe you just drop it after that.

```
sampleDF.drop(['date'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

First reset_index solves your porblem with the incomplete rows and then i would merge these two dataframes:

```
sampleDf = pd.DataFrame({'city': ['M', 'M', 'M','C'],
                         'avg_temp': [21, 32, 14,23],
                         'week': [1, 2, 3, 1]})
otherDF = pd.DataFrame({'city': ['M', 'M', 'C','M'],
                        'avg_temp_2020': [4, 25, 36,1],
                        'week': [1, 2, 1, 3]})

sampleDf = sampleDf.groupby(['city', 'avg_temp']).mean().reset_index()
sampleDf = sampleDf.merge(otherDF, left_on=['city', 'week'], right_on=['city', 'week'])
print(sampleDf)
```

Maybe for better understanding check the docu on the [merge method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html).